# How to access log4j variables in log4j.properties file

Tags: clojure, log4j

I am unable to access variables in my log4j.properties file from a clojure.clj file.

Specifically, I need to be able to use some clojure logic to see what level my log4j.rootLogger level is set to. Is there a way to reference/import/:require my log4j file within my clj file so that I can use some logic on the variables setup in the log4jfile?

I have the following in my log4j.properties file.

```
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
```

I want to be able to be able to use an if statement in my exceptions.clj file to be able to confirm when the log4j.rootlogger value in my log4j.properties file is set to INFO or OFF or DEBUG.

```
    (if (log4j.rootlogger=INFO) (prn "rootlogger is set to info") (prn "rootlogger is set to something else"))
```

Comment: It would help if you could show us some more details. How is your project set up, do you have some example code where you at least log some messages or even better tried out some things that didn't really work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it a quick try assuming the following:

- If you are configuring Log4j using a `log4j.properties` it means you are using Log4j 1.2 (which has reached end-of-life BTW)

I created a new project with `lein new app log4jdemo`, added a dependency on the Log4j JAR (got the artifact name from [this page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j/1.2.17)):

**project.clj**

```
(defproject log4jdemo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [log4j/log4j "1.2.17"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot log4jdemo.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Next, I modified the file `core.clj` generated from the template with the following:

**src/log4jdemo/core.clj**

```
(ns log4jdemo.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:import [org.apache.log4j Logger]))

(defn get-logging-level []
  (-> (Logger/getRootLogger)
      .getEffectiveLevel
      str))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Effective level:" (get-logging-level)))
```

Finally, let's add a configuration file. Note that the properties file needs to be placed in the `src` folder so that when we bundle the whole thing, it can be found as a resource (I'm using the `WARN` log level, but you can try any other [Level](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html)):

**src/log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout
```

Finally, we build the project as an Uberjar and run it:

```
$ lein uberjar
Compiling log4jdemo.core
Created /tmp/log4jdemo/target/uberjar/log4jdemo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created /tmp/log4jdemo/target/uberjar/log4jdemo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

$ java -jar target/uberjar/log4jdemo-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.stdout
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "stdout".
Effective level: WARN
```

... and that is correct, the Log4j properties file had been set to WARN in the example (`lein run` would also work, BTW).